# Display list as menu then expand div to fill remaining width

Tags: css, layout, html

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="1.php">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="2.php">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="3.php">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="4.php">Menu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="5.php">Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fillrest"></div>
</div>
```

How do I apply CSS to this to make the fixed-width #logo sit next to each list member and then the #fillrest div... fill the rest of the width. (#header width should be 100%).

Having real trouble with this one...

Gausie

Comment: The problem when thinking of this solution is with the `fillrest` div ... :). What's the need of `fillrest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery Solution:**

http://www.jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/aePGr/

**Preview:**

[image]